# C# downloading torrent with MonoTorrent

Tags: c#, mono, download, monotorrent, torrent

I'm trying to download a torrent with [MonoTorrent](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent), the problem is that when i look at the network traffic in wireshark it seems like the client is not even attempting to contact the tracker. It reads the torrent-file correctly and visual studio displays no errors.

This is the code i'm using:

```
public Form1()
{
        EngineSettings settings = new EngineSettings();
        settings.AllowedEncryption = EncryptionTypes.All;
        settings.SavePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "torrents");

        if (!Directory.Exists(settings.SavePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(settings.SavePath);

        engine = new ClientEngine(settings);

        engine.ChangeListenEndpoint(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6969));

        Torrent torrent = Torrent.Load("C:/Users/xxx/Google Drive/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/kontakt.torrent");

        TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, engine.Settings.SavePath, new TorrentSettings());

        engine.Register(manager);

        manager.Start();
}
```

I really appreciate any help or if someone knows about some alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Make sure you didn't create a private torrent.